# Regex doesn't match as I expect

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I have this string:
`'Slope fields are constructed by plotting tiny line segments at various points in the $xy$-plane. The slope of each line segment is given by the value of $f(x, y)$ at that corresponding point. These line segments collectively form a field of slopes, hence the name "slope field."'`

and also this regex: `/\S*\$\$?[^$]*\$\$?\S*/gi`

which I feel should match all phrases within single or double dollar signs $ as well as any text that surrounds it. so ideally  it should math `$xy$-plane.` and `$f(x, y)$`

but for some reason it matches: `$xy$-plane. The slope of each line segment is given by the value of $f(x,`

anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong or whats going on here?

I am expecting it to match $xy$-plane. and $f(x, y)$ but it doesn't

Comment: Maybe you just need to exclude `$` from `\S`? Try `[^\s$]*\$\$?[^$]*\$\$?[^\s$]*`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHg65S/1).

Comment: You could try running it through https://regex101.com

Comment: Since you don't care about the whitespace (0 or 1) before and after, just remove that and simplify your regex: `\$\$?(.+?)\$\$?` - this seems to match what you are looking for? I tend to use https://regexr.com/ to test regexes, and it has a handy cheatsheet for you to try.

Comment: How about being more exclusive and allowing only word characters and dashes (and maybe some more characters) before and/or after a character sequence enclosed by `$`? ... [`/[-\w]*\${1,2}.*?\${1,2}[-\w]*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/bx6gak/1)

Comment: @somethinghere i kinda needed it to match even the characters outside the dollar signs ($). at this point i've decided to not go this route anymore tho but thanks for your suggestion either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because regex by default take the longest match it can, you have to tell `*` to be "lazy" by adding a `?`.

```
\S*?\$\$?[^$]*\$\$?\S*
```

I suggest you to use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com): a nice site on wich you can test (ant that explains) the regex you're using

Also you can simplify your regex like this

```
\S*?\$[^$]*\$\S*
```

That is because `\S*` can capture also "outer" `$` so `$$hey$$ciao` would match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex to `/[^\s$]*\$[^$]+\$[^\s$]*/gi`.
That matches what you want it to match according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SpQJ9K/1):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like:

```
[^\s$]*\$[^$]+\$[^\s$]*
```

- `[^\s$]*` - match zero or more non-whitespace and not dollar sign characters before the opening dollar sign
- `\$` - opening dollar sign
- `[^$]+` - one or more not dollar signs
- `\$` - closing dollar sign
- `[^\s$]*` - zero or more non-whitespace and not dollar sign characters

https://regex101.com/r/ws0mn0/1

```js
const str = 'Slope fields are constructed by plotting tiny line segments at various points in the $xy$-plane. The slope of each line segment is given by the value of $f(x, y)$ at that corresponding run-on-sentence$()$followed-by-another$DHF$group point. These line segments collectively form a field of slopes, hence the name "slope field." and more some-$yz$-something else';

const match = str.match(/[^\s$]*\$[^$]+\$[^\s$]*/g);

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need smth like this

`/\S*?\$\$?[^$]*\$\$?\S*/gi`

That would grab all text inside dollar signs and surrounding text, which is not whitespace.